# How can I configure nvim to use a single escape to exit insert mode?

Tags: neovim

I was trying out nvim (neovim) for the first time and I find that I have to type `<escape>` twice to get out of insert mode.

I'm not sure if this is a feature or a [bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3593).  I see the same behaviour on both Mac and Linux (i.e. escape, followed by a move command such as 'k', inserts a k in my buffer).

Is there a way to configure this editor to use a single escape instead of two to get to NORMAL mode?

EDIT: I'm not using tmux (at least not explicitly).  I'd tried the tmux method of changing the timeout, but it produced a syntax error, so I wasn't sure that was the issue.  However, the issue I am seeing does appear to be timeout related nonetheless.  If I wait (an unnaturally long time compared to what I am used to), the editor does switch back to normal mode.

EDIT2.1: The software I am using is: Mac terminal + ssh + screen + nvim.  Initially it seemed like adding a .tmux.conf file (on my mac) with 'set -s escape-time 0' in it fixes this issue (on the mac), but I still see escape delays with terminal+ssh+screen+nvim and cause me to mess up my editing session after hitting escape and not waiting long enough.

Comment: Are you in tmux? (As the linked bug suggests)

Comment: Why don't you map two escapes to a single escape :D

Comment: What FDinoff said.  I just tested this and it does happen under `tmux`: neovim (and vim too) has a delay when pressing the `<esc>` key.  2 presses are not required, it is just a delay.

Comment: Also, see this [U&L question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior).  Maybe the delay is caused by that (it was for me).

Comment: grochmal.  That was it.  I didn't think that it was the mac terminal itself that was causing the issue, since vim didn't do this, just nvim.

Comment: Not necessarily the terminal, vim and nvim share a lot of input code. BUt cool, it really is certainly a delay then.  And is present in nvim but not vim.  Hmmm... what is the output of a plain `:imap` (without arguments)?  i.e. do you have the `<esc>` mapped in a multiple keystroke map?

Comment: :imap without arguments produces no results.

Comment: So it is screen this time.  We also [saw this before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow), try the `maptimeout 0` in `.screenrc` (on the machine running screen, i.e. the linux machine).  GNU screen has key mappings too.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the exactly same problem Mac terminal + ssh + screen + nvim, solved by setting empty guicursor

```
set guicursor=
```

Problem and solution are explained here: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6403

Comment: This doesn't really look like the same issue. Also, the solution is in no way general, instead, it is a solution that works to solve the issue at neovim#6403 for neovim run in specific terminal emulators (i.e. konsole in this case).